# Nested List problem from Automating the Boring Stuff with Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have been stuck on this for several hours and I can't figure out what the problem is with this nested dictionary. I have typed the code exactly the way it is displayed in the book, but it is still not working the way it should. For some reason the function only returns the values from the key 'Alice'. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
allGuests = {'Alice': {'apples': 5, 'pretzels': 12},
             'Bob': {'ham sandwiches': 3, 'apples': 2},
             'Carol': {'cups': 3, 'apple pies': 1}}
def totalBrought(guests, item):
    numBrought = 0
    for k, v in guests.items():
        numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item,0)
        return numBrought

print('Number of things being brought:')
print(' - Apples' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'apples')))
print(' - Cups' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'cups')))
print(' - Cakes ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests,'cakes')))
print(' - Ham Sandwiches ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'ham sandwiches')))
print(' - Apple Pies' + str(totalBrought(allGuests,'apple pies')))
```

The output of this code is supposed to be,

```
- Apples 7
- Cups 3
- Cakes 0
- Ham Sandwiches 3
- Apple pies 1
```

However I keep getting this as my output

```
- Apples 5
- Cups 0
- Cakes 0
- Ham Sandwiches 0
- Apple pies 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return statement is in the wrong place (inside the loop). Should be:

```
def totalBrought(guests, item):
    numBrought = 0
    for k, v in guests.items():
        numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item,0)
    return numBrought
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is almost correct, there's only this one part:**

```
    for k, v in guests.items():
        numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item,0)
        return numBrought
```

---

You see, in python, once the program meets a return statement in a function, the program will jump out of the function, right then and there.

---

Since you have a return statement in your for loop, the program never got to loop over it, so it only returns the values from the first iteration.

---

Fixed by removing an indent:

```
allGuests = {'Alice': {'apples': 5, 'pretzels': 12},
             'Bob': {'ham sandwiches': 3, 'apples': 2},
             'Carol': {'cups': 3, 'apple pies': 1}}
def totalBrought(guests, item):
    numBrought = 0
    for k, v in guests.items():
        numBrought = numBrought + v.get(item,0)
    return numBrought

print('Number of things being brought: ')
print(' - Apples ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'apples')))
print(' - Cups ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'cups')))
print(' - Cakes ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests,'cakes')))
print(' - Ham Sandwiches ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests, 'ham sandwiches')))
print(' - Apple Pies ' + str(totalBrought(allGuests,'apple pies')))
```

---

Output:

---

```
Number of things being brought: 
 - Apples 7
 - Cups 3
 - Cakes 0
 - Ham Sandwiches 3
 - Apple Pies 1
```

---

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation, this makes a lot of sense.